# JavaScript output with Smarty not visible in page source

Tags: javascript, smarty, output

I'm currently making some changes in page which uses Smarty engine. I'm confused with outputting JavaScript, because when I look into page source there is nothing outputted but when I'm using Firebug my outputted JavaScript code is visible. Is it normal behaviour for Smarty templates?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (isThanksPage == true) {ldelim}
     var biJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
     document.write('some javascript source code');
   {rdelim}

   if (isThanksPage === true) {ldelim}
      Order.SetCustomer('{$customerInfo.accountDetails.loginMail}', '{$customerInfo.shippingDetails.sFName}', '{$customerInfo.shippingDetails.sLName}');
      Order.OrderNumber = '{$orderId}';
      Order.OrderTotal = '{$totalAll|string_format:"%.2f"}';
      Order.ShippingTotal = '{if $shippingInfo.value eq 0}Free{else}${$shippingInfo.value|string_format:"%.2f"}{/if}';
   {rdelim}
</script>
      {assign var=totalWithoutTax value=`$total+$shippingInfo.value`}
      {if $tax}
        {assign var=taxValue value=`$tax*$totalWithoutTax/100`}
      {else}
        {assign var=taxValue value=0}
      {/if}
   {assign var=totalAll value=`$totalWithoutTax+$taxValue+$promoProduct.catalog_price`}
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (isThanksPage == true) {ldelim}
      Order.ItemTotal = '${$totalAll|string_format:"%.2f"}';      
   {rdelim}
</script>
      {foreach from=$cartProducts key=key item=product}
         {if $product.freeItemNum}
            <script type="text/javascript">
               if (isThanksPage == true) {ldelim}
               Order.AddLineItem('{$product.productInfo[1]}', {$product.freeItemNum}, '0.00');
               {rdelim}
            </script>
         {/if}

         {if $product.quantity > $product.freeItemNum}
            {assign var=quantity value=`$product.quantity-$product.freeItemNum`}
            {if $product.getYInfo.discountNumber >= $quantity}
               {assign var=priceValue value=`$quantity*$product.getYInfo.discountPrice`}
               {assign var=unitPriceValue value=`$product.getYInfo.discountPrice`}
            {elseif $product.getYInfo.discountNumber neq 0}
               {assign var=quantity1 value=`$quantity-$product.getYInfo.discountNumber`}
               {assign var=quantity2 value=`$product.getYInfo.discountNumber`}
               {assign var=priceValue value=`$quantity1*$product.sellPrice+$quantity2*$product.getYInfo.discountPrice`}
               {assign var=unitPriceValue value=`$product.sellPrice`}
            {else}
               {assign var=priceValue value=`$quantity*$product.sellPrice`}
               {assign var=unitPriceValue value=`$product.sellPrice`}
            {/if}
            <script type="text/javascript">
            if (isThanksPage == true) {ldelim}
            Order.AddLineItem('{$product.productInfo[1]}', {$quantity}, '${$priceValue|string_format:"%.2f"}');
            {rdelim}
            </script>
         {/if}
      {/foreach}
      <script type="text/javascript">
      if (isThanksPage == true) {ldelim}
      Order.Go();
      {rdelim}   
</script>
```

Comment: When you say "not outputting anything" do you mean there is no Javascript visible in the page source, or that the Javascript adds content to the page, and that content isn't visible in page source?

Comment: I think it is my mistake. I working with someone's code so I don't know how it works. After few hours of reading and trying I found, that  firebug returns current html code and CTRL+U return hoe page - that is page from redirection if no arguments are passed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show example of code? No, it's not normal behaviour